# Rows with hundreds of entries

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have data where each ID has hundreds of entries.

Here is the current setup I have chosen:

[image]

I see this as very messy as there is no fixed amount of entries. The database will only **ever** be queried via the ID. I need to say something along the lines of "Select all of the entries (1, 2, 3 etc) from table where the ID = 3". I feel the current setup is very messy and not practical at all. Is this way of doing this wrong? Ideally I need a better/more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Maybe a document based database would fit here better.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to select *, example: SELECT * FROM tablename where id = 3; You should also look at normalizing your tables. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Ask yourself: *What is the structure and relation of my data?*

Comment: @JoelLewis Sure, I could do that. But is it bad to have hundreds of columns?

Comment: In most cases it is not optimal.  What kind of data are you storing?  Also having column names as numbers makes it quite difficult for others to understand your code in the future.

Comment: @JoelLewis In the actual database the columns are named appropriately. Basically I'm storing names of children in a class room. For example, all the names in the class where the class (ID) = 1. Just imagine these are very big classes (50-150) :P

Comment: Are you trying to have a one-to-many relationship? Read something about basic normalized database design patterns.

Comment: A better design would be to have one table for the class with the columns ID, DESCRIPTION.  And then to have a second table with the columns CLASS_ID, STUDENT_ID, and a third table with he columns STUDENT_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME.  You can then use joins to gather the data you need. This will also help you avoid update and insertion anomalies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically I'm storing names of children in a class room.

Then you're looking for a one-to-many (or possibly many-to-many) relationship with tables like this:

```
TABLE class
id   INT  AUTO_INCREMENT
name TEXT

TABLE children
id       INT  AUTO_INCREMENT
class_id INT
name     TEXT
```